# discord.net how to convert to IEmote

Tags: .net, discord, discord.net

I am trying to receive reactions from a message that is sent by the discord bot

```
var message = await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("", false, MyEmbedBuilder.Build());
IReadOnlyCollection<IUser> temp = await message.GetReactionUsersAsync("", 1000, null);
```

when i try this i get this error

> Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'Discord.IEmote'

Comment: The error message is pretty self-explanatory: 'IUserMessage.GetReactionUsersAsync(IEmote, **int, RequestOptions**)'. You're missing two parameters from that function.

Comment: oh my bad i did the wrong error message. when i put the parameters i got cannot convert from string to Discord.IEmote

Answer (score 0):

You should probably spend some time looking at the [documentation](https://docs.stillu.cc/api/Discord.Emoji.html) provided. => [Emoji declaration](https://docs.stillu.cc/guides/emoji/emoji.html#emoji-declaration)